# When I'm iterating this field array I've got this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I'm trying to iterate through a FieldArray I'm obtaining from other file, in this case, FormDetailBill. I'm in FormBill.

This is my BillForm.jsx  . I'm importing FormDetailBill from FormDetailBill.jsx

```
       import FormDetailBill from './FormDetailBill';

      const selector = formValueSelector('bill');


           class BillForm extends Component {

                componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
                      if(this.props.isTotal !== prevProps.isTotal){

                        this.props.dispatch(

                       change('bill','total',this.props.isTotal)

                         )
                        }
                        }
              render(){


              const { handleSubmit, loading,submitting, pristine, reset,isTotal} = this.props;

                    if (loading) {
                     return <span>Loading...</span>;
                                   }

                      return (
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>


                          <FieldArray

                            name= 'detail'
                            component={FormDetailBill}
                            placeholder= '...detail'
                            label='Detail'

                                 />
                          <Field
                               name='total'
                               component={TotalWidget}
                               placeholder= '...total'
                               label='Total'
                             props={{calc: () =>{


                               this.props.bill.detail.reduce((total,detailItem) =>{

                           return total + detailItem.subtotal;

                                 },0)

                                   }}}
                                  > 
                              {isTotal}

                                   </Field>


                            </form>
           }


                 }


               BillForm = connect((state,props,index,fields) =>{

                 let quantity = [];

                 let price = [];

                 let subtotal = [];


                       const formValues = selector(state,`detail`);

                //In the following line is the error

                         formValues.map((detailItem,index) =>{


                         quantity[index] = selector(state,`detail.${index}.quantity`);
                         price[index] = selector(state,`detail.${index}.product.price`);
                         subtotal[index] = quantity[index] * price[index];




                          })


                         return{

                         isTotal: props.subtotal.reduce((total,subtotal) =>{

                            return total + subtotal;
                                },0)
                             }

                          })(BillForm)
```

I'm trying to iterate field array detail (

```
                                                const formValues = selector(state,`detail`);

                                                      //In the following line is the error

                                                     formValues.map((detailItem,index) =>{
```

) and I've got this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Anyone knows How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try adding 'formValues && ' before the map.

Comment: how should be in code?, I'm trying to do this:     formValues.formValues.map((detailItem,index) =>{

      });

Comment: `formValues && formValues.map((detailItem,index) =>{`

Comment: Another way: `if (formValues) formValues.map((detailItem,index) =>{`

Comment: I could solve. It was as you said.